# Какие есть библиотеки JS-слайдеров наподобие Vue Awesome Slider?

Tags: javascript, slider, поиск-библиотек

Какие есть библиотеки JS-слайдеров наподобие Vue Awesome Slider? 
Простого Slick.js не хватает, хотелось бы таких расширенных функций, как например в библиотеке Vue Awesome Slider, но данное расширение не знаю как использовать ввиду незнания Vue.js.

Comment: [Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/)

Comment: Вообще, чтобы использовать vue - не обязательно знать его в совершенстве...